# WiFi adaptor not found on Thinkpad x130E

Tags: networking, wireless

I have the same issue that others seem to have had but when I try the solutions listed there it doesn't work. It looks like the other solutions are very machine specific and beyond my level of expertise to make the adaptations needed to adjust the solution to my specific machine.

I do not have WiFi connection in Ubuntu but the adapter is seen in the terminal window.

This same version of Ubuntu worked on this machine until I pulled a failing hard drive and replaced it with an SSD. The reinstall ended up with this new WiFi problem.

***Tools→Settings→WiFi*** window says "No WiFi adapter found"
while the terminal display shown below sees the expected adapter.
However the terminal window says that the adapter is "DISABLED".

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
*-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: e0:06:e6:c2:87:7f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192ce driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:d1500000-d1503fff
```

Output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list all`?

Comment: nan@nan-ThinkPad-X130e:~$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
nan@nan-ThinkPad-X130e:~$

Comment: WiFi is hard blocked. It means it is disabled by the hardware. Is there any network key on the keyboard? Try pressing that. Also check whether wireless connections are enabled from BIOS.

Comment: This machine has no hardware switch for WiFi nor does it have an F key for that.

Comment: It does have an airport F key, but the AIRPORT feature is current not on.

Comment: Another interesting point is that the BlueTooth IS turned on

Comment: Also, Kulfy, I want you to know that I have not slobbered on the keyboard.